# Fixing USB problem in PIC18f

Tags: pic, usb-device, c18

I am working on PIC18f controllers with USB peripherals and i would like to take advice from those who have worked in similar field.
How do you deal with things like:

1.Some times My pic enumerates well showing Device Recognized and some times it pops up like Unknown device.
What should be the real cause and how can i fix it?

Im confused about where to look for leaks in this problem.

> The firmware for the USB communication is taken from this:
>   http://18f4550.com/updated_USB_demo_board/updated_USB_demo_board.html

I suspect this is not a h/w problem as i'm using a crystal oscillator of 16mhz.
I would like to have your insights to debug this project.

Yours faithfully

Arookie

Comment: There can be lots of things that can cause this so maybe you could include a schematic of what you've built. Also at least a brief description of the firmware (if the code is too long to post in complete form). I guess you're probably using the Microchip USB stack?

Comment: Its a modified code @PeterJ.Its used for the project.The h/w connections are done properly .

Comment: http://18f4550.com/updated_USB_demo_board/updated_USB_demo_board.html .Im using the USB source file from this site.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

The cause was the tolerance and stability of the chosen oscillator.
I had chosen a ceramic resonator and this was not stable enough for operating the USB. Sometimes I got Unknown device. I replaced my clock source by a crystal with the right stability and tolerance and everything worked perfectly.

What kind of clock source do you use? what is its tolerance? Do you have any mean of measuring the clock of your system?(without probing the source directly, which could change its frequency)

Comment: Well Thank you@Blup1980 .Well i m using a Crystal oscillator of 16mhz here.How do you check whether you got the right stability and tolerance.I thought crystal oscillators were a standard thing.

Comment: Check its tolerance (in ppm) in the datasheet. I think that there is something in the PIC datasheet about the min requirement in case of USB usage. Also make sure you use the right load caps on the crystal because that could change its  center frequency.

Comment: Thank you @Blup1980 .Actually the caps were all right.But i trust The USB interrupts must be the problem it seems.